# Can i change the network section of my conky to support my wifi?

Tags: 12.04, networking, scripts, conky

So I've been having fun with setting up my new conky which I downloaded recently (i'm running Ubuntu 12.04).  I am having a problem with the section of the conky which measures network parameters.  I've looked at the .conkyrc_net file and I have found sections which mention Eth1 several times.  I wanted to know if I changed this code to wlan0 would it correct the problem i am having and begin measuring my wifi network parameters?

I am very new to linux and have no code writing experience but I have spent the last two days researching it and would like to try and fix this.

here is the code from the conkyrc_net file:

```
background yes
font ubuntu:size=8
xftfont ubuntu:size=8
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.5
update_interval 1.0
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent no
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders yes
border_width 1
draw_graph_borders yes
minimum_size 180
maximum_width 220
default_color 5382BA
default_shade_color 000000
own_window_colour 191919
color3 737373 #graph border
color2 FFFFFF #title
color1 FFFFFF #text
color0 FFA500 #icon
alignment top_right
gap_x 30
gap_y 656
no_buffers yes
cpu_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale yes
uppercase no
use_spacer none
temperature_unit fahrenheit

TEXT
${color0}${font ConkySymbols:size=16}i${font}${color}  ${color2}NETWORK»${color}
${color1}Up $alignr${upspeed eth1}k/s
${color3}${upspeedgraph eth1 20,183 474747 E9E9E9}${color}
${color1}Total Up $alignr${totalup eth1}${color}

${color1}Down $alignr${downspeed eth1}k/s
${color3}${downspeedgraph eth1 20,183 474747 E9E9E9}${color}
${color1}Total Down $alignr${totaldown eth1}${color}

${color1}Local IP $alignr${addr eth1}
External IP $alignr${execi 1 ~/.scripts/ip.sh}${color}
```

I'm assuming this is the file where the problems lies only from its _net reference:)

Any help would be much appreciated  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing to wlan0 might work.

this is my 'wireless section' of my conky... (for reference)

${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan1}${color1}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}ACTIVE NETWORK: wlan1${hr 2 }
${voffset 2}${font VariShapes Solid:pixelsize=12}q${goto 18}${voffset -3}${font}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan1} ${alignr}${color3}${upspeedgraph wlan1 20,160}${color1}
${font}${voffset -24}${goto 18}Total: ${color2}${totalup wlan1}${color1}
${voffset -3}${font VariShapes Solid:pixelsize=12}Q${goto 18}${voffset -3}${font}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan1} ${alignr}${color3}${downspeedgraph wlan1 20,160}${color1}
${font}${voffset -24}${goto 18}Total: ${color2}${totaldown wlan1}
${color1}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}WIRELESS${hr 2 }
${voffset -2}${font VariShapes Solid:pixelsize=12}-${goto 18}${voffset -0}${font Liberation:style=normal:pixelsize=12}Wireless Access Point: ${color2}${alignr}${wireless_essid wlan1}
${color1}${voffset 2}${font Stylebats:pixelsize=12}Z${goto 18}${voffset -3}${font Liberation:style=normal:pixelsize=12}Connection Strength: ${color2}${alignr}${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan1}%
${color1}${voffset 2}${font Stylebats:pixelsize=12}C${goto 18}${voffset -3}${font Liberation:style=normal:pixelsize=12}Connection Max Throughput: ${color2}${alignr}${wireless_bitrate wlan1}
${color1}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}${voffset -3}${hr 2}
${voffset -1}${font Poky:pixelsize=12}w${goto 19}${voffset -1}${font Liberation:style=normal:pixelsize=12}Local IP: ${color2}${alignr}${addr wlan1}
${color1}${voffset -1}${font Poky:pixelsize=12}w${goto 19}${voffset -1}${font Liberation:style=normal:pixelsize=12}Internet IP:${color2}${alignr}${execi 300 ~/.scripts/ip.sh}${else}${endif}

my conky is really crunched up because there is 'alot of stuff' and it makes it fit just right.  extra line spaces in your conky config will extend your conky down your desktop.

Comment: Thank You for your swift reply, it gave me the gut to go ahead and do my first code changes:)  I changed to wlan0 for every instance where it occured in the code, and now my meters are running:)  They are reading 418Bk/s up, total up 0 and 470Bk/s down, total down 218 MiB.  Could you tell me what the B in the Bk/s refers to please? should it be there?  Thanks again:)

Comment: @DavidGriffiths It should be 'KB' (Kilobyte) or 'kb' (Kilobit).

Comment: I thought as much, it just seemed odd as there is no 'B' in the code:)